# C++ array of inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

The question is about C++. I have 3 classes: the first, named `MovieMaker`, is abstract, the second, named `Actor`, is derived from the first one and the third, named 'Director' derives from `Actor`. I want to create an array that can hold instances of both Actor and Director.
How can I do that?

Comment: A director is an actor?

Comment: I know every actor wants to direct, I didn't know it went the other way, too.

Comment: I know it's not your question, but your inheritance hierarchy sounds a bit suspect. It may be worth considering a different structure. For example, you could try: MovieMaker is a concrete class; Role is abstract; Director and Actor inherit from Role and each MovieMaker *has a* number of Roles. This is slightly more complex, but would be more flexible and avoid weirdness for directors who don't act.

Comment: Inheritance is not the only tool available. Consider if that's what you really want.

Answer (score 3):

create an array of `MovieMaker` pointers. it can hold pointers to derived classes. This technique is called polymorphism - here is a nice tutorial:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

Comment: cplusplus.com is bad and you should feel bad

Comment: @TonyTheLion - really? I used it many times for reference before stackoverflow was around. why is it so bad?

Comment: because it has lots of errors and misinformation. Use en.cppreference.com instead.

Answer (score 3):

Create an array of `std::shared_ptr<MovieMaker>`, or `unique_ptr`.  In C++, it is usually a good idea to create a `std::vector` instead of a raw array: so `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MovieMaker>> vec`, which you populate like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

// later:
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MovieMaker>> vec;
vec.push_back( std::make_shared<Actor>() );
vec.push_back( std::make_shared<Director>() );
vec.push_back( std::make_shared<Actor>() );
```

or, in C++11:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

// later:
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MovieMaker>> vec = {
  std::make_shared<Actor>(),
  std::make_shared<Director>(),
  std::make_shared<Actor>(),
};
```

If you are willing to use `boost`, a 3rd party library, there are a few other options.

Alternatively, create an array of `boost::variant<Actor,Director>`, which ignores the class hierarchy and simply stores a type-safe `union` like construct.  `boost::variant` is a bit trick to use.

As another alternative, `boost::any` can store anything, and you can query it if what it has is what you want.

Comment: Well, maybe, if all the objects are allocated on the heap and the design calls for shared ownership. But that's an assumption in this answer, not part of the original question.

Comment: @PeteBecker The objects are in a `std::vector` already, which means they are on the free store regardless.  I added a level of indirection, which (unless you a trick like `boost::variant` or `boost::any`) is required for polymorphic storage in `std::vector`.  I chose `shared_ptr` rather than raw pointers, because raw pointers are more complex.  `unique_ptr` is another alternative.  I stored it in a `vector`, because `vector` is a good default container to use -- there are good reasons to use raw arrays, but they are corner cases.

Comment: Um, no, they're not already in a `std::vector`. But if they are, the vector manages their storage, and creating smart pointers (`shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, or anything else that manages storage) that point to them would create a disaster.

Comment: Sorry, my description was backwards (I justified `vector` after `shared_ptr` -- my bad).  Regardless, barring union-type tricks, the only way to store polymorphic instances in C++ is in the free store.  I covered a few union-type tricks that lets you store polymorophic instances in automatic storage, but they are trickier than using the free store.  What, exactly, do you find missing from my explanation?

Comment: `Derived d; Base &b = d;` No free store here, but b acts polymorphically. More generally, if you have a container that holds pointers to a base type, it doesn't matter whether the pointed-to objects are on the free store or not; the pointers act polymorphically. But my objection is exactly what I said in my first comment: the proposed solution makes assumptions about object lifetime management that are not part of the original question. Smart pointers can be a valid part of a design, but they should not be added as a reflex action.

Comment: No, you didn't polymorphically store data there -- you polymorphically referenced data.  There is a difference.  The original poster wanted an array that *held* data polymorphically.  *Holding* data implies union-like tricks, or pointers-with-ownership.  Regardless, I encourage you to post your own answer to this question!

Comment: I agree: I didn't polymorphically store data. And, oddly enough, I didn't say that I did. Please don't put words into my mouth. I can speak for myself.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm sorry, where did I say you said that?  I simply pointed out why your objection is irrelevant to the question at hand, as the question at hand is about arrays that *hold instances of* polymorphic data.